# When we calculate the irr, how to decide the initial range of irr?

Tags: analysis

For the cash flow $C_i$, initial investment costs $P$ which is negative, the number of time period $i$, when we calculate the irr $r$, how to decide the initial range of $r$?
$$P + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{C_i}{(1+r)^{i}} = 0 $$
I want to use newton method or brent method to calculate the r.
But at first, I need to know the range of r.
Usually, it used to be (0, 1). But it can be negative or greater than 1.

Comment: Please define all the variables used in your displayed equation. [Another thing: You certainly *cannot* have $r=-1.$ It would make a zero denominator.]

Comment: I have updated my question@coffeemath

Comment: If I understand your question, you want to solve that equation for $r$, using (say) Newton's Method, and you want to know how to choose a starting approximation for $r$. Generally, it doesn't matter too much. Start with any value you like for $r$, say, $0.5$, and then run Newton, and chances re it will converge to an answer.

Comment: Whaddya think, Paul?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I still need a range.lol. I am reading this paper.https://faculty.e-ce.uth.gr/akritas/phd_thesis_vigklas.pdf

Comment: I'd like to know whether I understand your question, and whether you understand my comment. Then maybe we can talk usefully about "range".

Comment: Yoo-hoo, Paul, where are you?

Comment: hey, @GerryMyerson .I use inequation to get a range. When r>0, its range is (-nc/p)(1/n)-1 to -nc/p -1. lol.

Comment: and @GerryMyerson, In that paper(page 7), using the Lagrange–MacLaurin Method, I can get a upper bound 1-c/p.

Comment: OK, let's start at the beginning. Are you, or are you not, trying to solve the equation you've posted for $r$?

Comment: yes, I am trying to solve this equation. although in newton method it does not need a range, a good initial value is enough. But in brent method it needs a range to do it. So I want to calculate a range.

Comment: @GerryMyerson lol

Comment: In the body of the question, you say you're OK with using the Newton method. And you write in the comment that the Newton method doesn't need a range. So why not just use the Newton method? Then you don't need a range.